# ERROR! failed to combine variables, expected dicts but got a 'dict' and a 'AnsibleUnicode'

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I have a very weird issue that I am unable to resolve. Already spent 4 hours on debugging but without any progress, never encountered something like this before.

Ansible's information:

```
ansible [core 2.11.5]
  config file = /Users/igor/Projects/infrastructure/mint2/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/igor/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/igor/.local/share/virtualenvs/mint2-x8LdeqZ_/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/igor/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /Users/igor/.local/share/virtualenvs/mint2-x8LdeqZ_/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.6 (default, Jun 28 2021, 19:24:41) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)]
  jinja version = 3.0.1
  libyaml = False
```

Here is a sample playbook:

```
---
- hosts: somehost
  gather_facts: yes
  vars_files:
    - host_vars/somehost/common/common.yml
    - host_vars/somehost/backup/backup.yml
  pre_tasks:
   - name: Prepare | Remove AppArmor
     apt:
       name: apparmor
       state: absent
   
   - name: Prepare | Stop AppArmor
     service:
       name: apparmor
       enabled: no
  roles: 
    - roles/role-provision-common
    - roles/role-deploy-backup
```

Here is the structure of the `host_vars`:

```
host_vars/somehost
├── backup
│   ├── backup.yml
│   └── encryption_key
├── common
│   ├── common.yml
│   └── ssh-keys
│       ├── id_rsa_backup
│       └── id_rsa_backup.pub
```

Here is the content of the `common.yml`:

```
common_packages_generic_enabled: true
common_packages_stats_enabled: true
common_packages_mysql_enabled: true
common_packages_web_server_enabled: false
common_network_rename_interfaces: true
common_preferred_timezone: 'UTC'
```

Here is the content of the `backup.yml`:

```
backup_server_hostname: someserver
backup_server_path: /home/someuser
backup_server_user: somerserver
backup_server_port: '22'
backup_host_user: someremoteuser
backup_host_mount_path: /home/someremoteuser/backup
backup_host_user_private_key_path: host_vars/somehost/common/ssh-keys/id_rsa_backup
```

The `encryption_key` and `id_rsa_backup` and `id_rsa_backup_pub` are vault encrypted files.

So, when I run:

```
ansible-playbook --check --diff somehost.yml -vvvvvvvv
```

I receive the following error:

```
PLAY [somehost] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Found a vault_id (default) in the vaulttext
We have a secret associated with vault id (default), will try to use to decrypt /Some/Local/Path/host_vars/somehost/backup/encryption_key
Trying to use vault secret=(FileVaultSecret(filename='/Some/Local/Path/.vault')) id=default to decrypt /Some/Local/Path/host_vars/somehost/backup/encryption_key
Trying secret FileVaultSecret(filename='/Some/Local/Path/.vault') for vault_id=default
Decrypt of "b'/Some/Local/Path/host_vars/somehost/backup/encryption_key'" successful with secret=FileVaultSecret(filename='/Some/Local/Path/.vault') and vault_id=default
Found a vault_id (default) in the vaulttext
We have a secret associated with vault id (default), will try to use to decrypt None
Trying to use vault secret=(FileVaultSecret(filename='Some/Local/Path/.vault')) id=default to decrypt None
Trying secret FileVaultSecret(filename='Some/Local/Path/.vault') for vault_id=default
Decrypt successful with secret=FileVaultSecret(filename='Some/Local/Path/.vault') and vault_id=default


ERROR! failed to combine variables, expected dicts but got a 'dict' and a 'AnsibleUnicode':
{'backup_server_hostname': 'somehost', 'backup_server_path': '/home/somehostpath', 'backup_server_user': 'somehostpath', 'backup_server_port': '22', 'backup_host_user': 'automator', 'backup_host_mount_path': '/home/xxxx/mnt/backup', 'backup_host_user_private_key_path': 'host_vars/somehost/common/ssh-keys/id_rsa_backup', 'backup_borgmatic_configuration': [{'source_directories': ['/home/xxxx/.mysql'], 'repositories': ['/home/xxxx/mnt/backup/backup'], 'application_name': 'somehost_db', 'location': {'exclude_if_present': '.nobackup'}, 'storage': {'encryption_passphrase': 'xxxxx', 'archive_name_format': "'{hostname}-mysql-{now}'"}, 'retention': {'keep_hourly': '168', 'prefix': "'{hostname}-mysql-'"}, 'consistency': {'checks': ['archives'], 'check_repositories': ['/home/xxxx/mnt/backup/backup']}, 'hooks': {'before_backup': ['sh /home/xxxx/.scripts/check_sshfs.sh', 'sh /home/xxxx/.scripts/mysql_backup.sh', 'echo "Starting a backup."'], 'after_backup': ['echo "Backup done"'], 'on_error': ['echo "Backup failed"']}}]}
"BORG_KEY 36dfe604435ad8eaca89e39 hqlhbGdvcml0aG2mc2hhMjU2pGRhdGHaAN5a1XnA0c3O3MC44+lN2nWgol31naZud/Gf1p Q2aDmnXeMj7pHR1LPL/K/b3vrBgWW64RV6e9E9PSsYicrLcYDrPA0s2YSHbZpTBBPKURxX h0uIhTTj8497vhiezwQOhjDxFpVPtzqWmlmz9ibQlrGCiBQQD95+NitfFJTBUoQ7HS+rgs /m87v8rQaOWhv6/4V9w1K4ooMu5ufMxNeUXUfidFJNs5HeJf2QS2iTd7dSBYLUmId5guZT PTypFvdtpsnUfXGQ5l0rluAgd1BigYxCtvdNwNRus88y9nc74y+kaGFzaNoAIN8uIPII2m Fzh6ZxBaG21vIbDFnFZHWjxBZwO+1MGz5Fqml0ZXJhdGlvbnPOAAGGoKRzYWx02gAgIpO9 oD"
```

The part before BORG_KEY sequence is the content of the `backup/backup.yml` file, and the text after that is decrypted `encyption_key`.

In order to run this playbook I have to remove `encryption_key` and `id_rsa_backup` and `id_rsa_backup_pub` files.

But - here is a weird part - I have another 5 playbooks which run same roles and have practically same host_vars structure and vault encrypted files, but they run just fine without need to remove encrypted files. So in half cases it doesn't work, and in other half it does work. And they all belong to the same groups.

I have no clue why is this happening and why Ansible tries to include files that I haven't specifically asked for.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: I also found out that if I add any extension to the encrypted files (.key and .pem), my playbook works fine. And I have no idea why.

Comment: You will want to read the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section of the how to ask guide, since you have shown filenames, and the inclusion of roles, but not some code that a SO user who wanted to help you could run and reproduce your circumstance. Good luck

Comment: @mdaniel forgot about that, updated my initial post.

Comment: Great question, thanks for asking. @Bubzsan's answer was helpful, as one of my `vault.yaml` file was indeed invalid.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem as you. In my case I defined my vault as vault.yaml.
But the problem is that I forgot it was a YAML file and defined the content as:

```
vault_db_password=somepassword
```

In my group_vars I had a var file that made a reference to the vault, like:

```yaml
configuration:
  rds:
    password: "{{ vault_db_password }}"
```

To fix it I simply had to make sure my vault was a valid yaml, so I changed the contents to:

```yaml
vault_db_password: somepassword
```

From your update it seems that ansible had a hard time understanding the file type, and probably errored out when parsing/casting and merging the variables because of that. Hope this helps someone, cheers!

Comment: I had similar problem, but my = was in host_vars/host_name file. It is yaml file too.